# cannot find package trycatch in tcl

Tags: tcl

I am writing the code this and I am finding the error "can't find package trycatch".

```
package require trycatch
namespace import trycatch
package require tcom
package require html
package require Thread
package require tdom
package require SQL

try {
    global configFileValues
    global File
    set logFolder "D:/Work/Smart Test/Logs"

    set windowTextOrWebUrl [lindex $argv 0]
    puts "WindowText: $windowTextOrWebUrl"
    # regsub -all {\[} "$windowTextOrWebUrl" {\[} windowTextOrWebUrl
    # puts "WindowText: $windowTextOrWebUrl"

    proc CreateSqlConnection {} {
        global odbcHandle
        set odbcHandle [SQL::SQLDriverConnect "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver};server=localhost;database=smarttest;user=root;password=pass"]
        return $odbcHandle
    }
    proc ReleaseSqlConnection {} {
        global odbcHandle
        set disconnectVal [$odbcHandle SQLDisconnect]
        # puts $disconnectVal
    }
    proc LogMaintenance {} {
        global logFolder
        global File
        set Time [clock seconds]
        set startTime [clock format $Time -format "%Y-%m-%d"]
        # puts "$logFolder"
        if {[file isdirectory $logFolder] == 0} {
            file mkdir $logFolder
        }
        set fileName "Logs"
        set extension ".txt"
        set logFile [concat $logFolder/$startTime$extension]
        set File [open $logFile a]
        return $File
    }
    proc GetWebControls {url} {
        global odbcHandle
        set iapp [tcom::ref createobj "InternetExplorer.Application"]
        $iapp Visible 1
        $iapp Navigate $url
        while {[$iapp Busy]} { after 500 }
        after 500
        set doc [$iapp Document]
        set body [$doc body]
        set elements [$body all]

        for {set i 0} {$i < [$elements length]} {incr i} {
            set controlType "NULL"
            set controlId "NULL"
            set controlName "NULL"
            set controlCaption "NULL"
            set controlDefaultValue "NULL"
            set controlType [[$elements item $i] getAttribute type]
            puts "ControlType: $controlType"
            switch $controlType {
                "button" {
                    puts "Button"
                }
                "text" {
                    # puts "Text"
                    set controlId [[$elements item $i] getAttribute id]
                    set controlCaption [[$elements item $i] getAttribute name]
                    set controlDefaultValue [[$elements item $i] getAttribute value]
                    set sqlQuery "Insert into t_controls (cntType, cntIndex, cntName, cntDefaultValue, cntCaption, cntScrId, modifiedBy, modifiedOn,    createdBy,createdOn)
                    Values ('$controlType',NULL,'$controlId','$controlDefaultValue','$controlCaption',1,'BalGovind',NOW(),'BalGovind',NOW())"
                    # puts $sqlQuery
                    set queryResult [$odbcHandle SQLExecDirect $sqlQuery]
                    puts "Query result in WebControl(): $queryResult"
                }
                "submit" {
                    # puts "submit"
                    set controlId [[$elements item $i] getAttribute id]
                    set controlName [[$elements item $i] getAttribute name]
                    set controlCaption [[$elements item $i] getAttribute value]
                    set sqlQuery "Insert into t_controls (cntType, cntIndex, cntName, cntDefaultValue, cntCaption, cntScrId, modifiedBy, modifiedOn,    createdBy,createdOn)
                    Values ('$controlType',NULL,'$controlId',NULL,'$controlCaption',1,'BalGovind',NOW(),'BalGovind',NOW())"
                    # puts $sqlQuery
                    set queryResult [$odbcHandle SQLExecDirect $sqlQuery]
                    puts "Query result in WebControl(): $queryResult"
                }
                "password" {
                    # puts "password"
                    set controlId [[$elements item $i] getAttribute id]
                    set controlCaption [[$elements item $i] getAttribute name]
                    set controlDefaultValue [[$elements item $i] getAttribute value]
                    set sqlQuery "Insert into t_controls (cntType, cntIndex, cntName, cntDefaultValue, cntCaption, cntScrId, modifiedBy, modifiedOn,    createdBy,createdOn)
                    Values ('$controlType',NULL,'$controlId','$controlDefaultValue','$controlCaption',1,'BalGovind',NOW(),'BalGovind',NOW())"
                    # puts $sqlQuery
                    set queryResult [$odbcHandle SQLExecDirect $sqlQuery]
                    puts "Query result in WebControl(): $queryResult"
                }
                "label" {
                    # puts "label"
                    set controlId [[$elements item $i] getAttribute id]
                    set controlCaption [[$elements item $i] getAttribute value]
                    set sqlQuery "Insert into t_controls (cntType, cntIndex, cntName, cntDefaultValue, cntCaption, cntScrId, modifiedBy, modifiedOn,    createdBy,createdOn)
                    Values ('$controlType',NULL,'$controlId','$controlDefaultValue','$controlCaption',1,'BalGovind',NOW(),'BalGovind',NOW())"
                    # puts $sqlQuery
                    set queryResult [$odbcHandle SQLExecDirect $sqlQuery]
                    puts "Query result in WebControl(): $queryResult"
                }
            }
            unset controlType
            unset controlId
            unset controlName
            unset controlCaption
            unset controlDefaultValue
        }
    }
    proc GetWindowControls {windowText} {
        set app [::tcom::ref createobj "ManagedSpy.Utility.Utility"]
        set bool [$app FetchControls $windowText]
        if {$bool == 0} {               
            exit
        }
    }
    proc GetControls {screenName} {
        global windowTextOrWebUrl
        set screenName $windowTextOrWebUrl
        if {([regexp "www." "$screenName" matchedString]) || ([regexp "http" "$screenName" matchedString])} {
            puts "Web Application."
            GetWebControls $screenName
        } else {
            puts "Window Application."
            GetWindowControls $screenName
        }
    }
    proc Main {} {
        puts "Executing Main Procedure!!!"
        global File
        global odbcHandle
        global windowTextOrWebUrl
        set File [LogMaintenance]
        set currentTime [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%H-%M-%S-%p"]
        puts $File "$currentTime :: Script started."
        set odbcHandle [CreateSqlConnection]
        GetControls $windowTextOrWebUrl
        ReleaseSqlConnection
        puts $File "[clock format [clock seconds] -format "%H-%M-%S-%p"] :: Script ends.\n\n######################################### \n"
        close $File
    } 
} 
catch -msg msg -code code -info info {
    puts "catch"
    puts "$msg $info"
    puts $File "[clock format [clock seconds] -format "%H-%M-%S-%p"] :: Exception - $msg \n $code \n $info \n"
    puts $File "[clock format [clock seconds] -format "%H-%M-%S-%p"] :: Script is ended.\n\n################################################## \n"
    close $File
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trycatch` package's documentation is [online](http://www.wjduquette.com/tcl/trycatch.html), and I'd guess that the sources are [here](http://www.wjduquette.com/tcl/trycatch20.zip). However, you probably ought to consider switching to Tcl 8.6 which has built-in [equivalent functionality](http://tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/try.htm).

Your code appears to have other problems too. Procedures rarely need to be declared inside an error-catching context; it's much more usual to put the *calls* to those procedures inside…

Comment: but now i m getting error in 2nd line that is "namespace import trycatch". the error is no namespace specified in import pattern trycatch

Comment: Get rid of both the `package require trycatch` and the `namespace import` line (which is buggy).